# AdMob iOS native ads issue

Tags: ios, sdk, admob, native

I am trying to implement admob native ads in my project. But I am getting an error like:

> "Request Error: Received invalid response."

I am using GADAdLoader for getting ads. 
[Here is my code](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native) ,

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your ADUnitID is identical to the one provided to you by AdMob.

Comment: @DanielStorm i am using admob provide adunit id: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511

Comment: @Ankur I have the same issue, did you manage to fix this ?

Comment: @Salah AdMob native ads is not for all user.